# Finding a corresponding leaf node for each data point in a decision tree (scikit-learn)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm using decision tree classifier from the scikit-learn package in python 3.4, and I want to get the corresponding leaf node id for each of my input data point.

For example, my input might look like this:

```
array([[ 5.1,  3.5,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.9,  3. ,  1.4,  0.2],
       [ 4.7,  3.2,  1.3,  0.2]])
```

and let's suppose the corresponding leaf nodes are 16, 5 and 45 respectively. I want my output to be:

```
leaf_node_id = array([16, 5, 45])
```

I have read through the scikit-learn mailing list and related questions on SF but I still can't get it to work. Here is some hint I found on the mailing list, but still does not work.

http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/31728624/

At the end of the day, I just want to have a function GetLeafNode(clf, X_valida) such that its output is a list of corresponding leaf nodes. Below is the code that reproduces the error I received. So, any suggestion will be very appreciated.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

# load data and divide it to train and validation
iris = load_iris()

num_train = 100
X_train = iris.data[:num_train,:]
X_valida = iris.data[num_train:,:]

y_train = iris.target[:num_train]
y_valida = iris.target[num_train:]

# fit the decision tree using the train data set
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Now I want to know the corresponding leaf node id for each of my training data point
clf.tree_.apply(X_train)

# This gives the error message below:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-2ecc95213752> in <module>()
----> 1 clf.tree_.apply(X_train)

_tree.pyx in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.apply (sklearn/tree/_tree.c:19595)()

ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'DTYPE_t' but got 'double'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally got it to work. Here is one solution based on my correspondence [message](http://sourceforge.net/p/scikit-learn/mailman/message/34142035/) in the scikit-learn mailing list:

After scikit-learn version 0.16.1, apply method is implemented in `clf.tree_`, therefore, I followed the following steps:

1. update scikit-learn to the latest version (0.16.1) so that you can use `apply` method from `clf.tree_`
2. convert the input data arrays (`X_train`, `X_valida`) from `float64` to `float32` using: `X_train = X_train.astype('float32')`
3. Now you can use `apply` method in this way: `clf.tree_.apply(X_train)` and you will get the leaf node id for each data point.

Here is the final code:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

# load data and divide it to train and validation
iris = load_iris()

num_train = 100
X_train = iris.data[:num_train,:]
X_valida = iris.data[num_train:,:]

y_train = iris.target[:num_train]
y_valida = iris.target[num_train:]

# convert data to float32
X_train = X_train.astype('float32')

# fit the decision tree using the train data set
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Now I want to know the corresponding leaf node id for each of my training data point
clf.tree_.apply(X_train)

# This gives the leaf node id:
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Answer (score 9):

Since scikit-learn 0.17 you can use the **apply** method of the DecisionTree object to get the index of the leaves where the data points end in the tree. Building on neobot's answer:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

# load data and divide it to train and validation
iris = load_iris()

num_train = 100
X_train = iris.data[:num_train,:]
X_valida = iris.data[num_train:,:]

y_train = iris.target[:num_train]
y_valida = iris.target[num_train:]

# fit the decision tree using the train data set
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Compute the leaf node id for each of my training data points
clf.apply(X_train)
```

Produces the output

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: Quick question, how to understand which node is at what index